# Weblogic server arguments via Admin Console

Tags: weblogic

I'm working on a Weblogic domain where I have deployed a Web Application on the Admin server node.

[image: Admin Server]

I want to pass an argument when the server starts. I'm trying to do this via the **Admin Console**, more specifically *Servers -> Admin -> Server Start -> Arguments* as depicted below

[image: Server start - Console]

But I don't see the arguments in the Server log.
What should be done in order the argument to take effect?

Answer (score 0):

After asking a coworker the answer was you can't start/stop a managed server or any other server without interacting with the `Node Manager`.
As depicted below the `Admin Console` instruct the `NodeManager`.

[image: Graph of Admin console and Node manager]

A useful instructing video on how to start the nodemanager and restart servers via console can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFEnMmPY4mQ).